# regex_iterator not matching groups in regular expression

Tags: regex, c++11

**How to extract Test and Again from string s in below code**.
Currently I am using regex_iterator and it doesn't seems to be matching groups in regular expression and I am getting {{Test}} and {{Again}} in output.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "<abc>{{Test}}</abc><def>{{Again}}</def>";
    std::regex rgx("\\{\\{(\\w+)\\}\\}");
    std::smatch match;
    std::sregex_iterator next(s.begin(), s.end(), rgx);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (next != end) {
      std::smatch match = *next;
      std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
      next++;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried using regex_search but it is not working with multiple patterns and only giving **Test** ouput

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "<abc>{{Test}}</abc><def>{{Again}}</def>";
    std::regex rgx("\\{\\{(\\w+)\\}\\}");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s, match, rgx,std::regex_constants::match_any))
    {
        std::cout<<"Match size is "<<match.size()<<std::endl;
        for(auto elem:match)
        std::cout << "match: " << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

Also as a side note why two backslashes are needed to escape { or }

Comment: All you need is to [replace `match.str()` with `match.str(1)` to access Group 1 value](https://ideone.com/ToCDTE) (in the first snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the contents of the capturing group you need to use `.str(1)`:

```
std::cout << match.str(1) << std::endl;
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/S5tUJK):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "<abc>{{Test}}</abc><def>{{Again}}</def>";
    // std::regex rgx("\\{\\{(\\w+)\\}\\}");
    // Better, use a raw string literal:
    std::regex rgx(R"(\{\{(\w+)\}\})");
    std::smatch match;
    std::sregex_iterator next(s.begin(), s.end(), rgx);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (next != end) {
      std::smatch match = *next;
      std::cout << match.str(1) << std::endl;
      next++;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test
Again
```

Note you do not have to use double backslashes to define a regex escape sequence inside *raw* string literals (here, `R"(pattern_here)"`).

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code.Also do you have any idea why we need two backslashes for { and }

Comment: @Kapil: You do not need to double them if you use a raw string literal. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think i am using raw string literal and without two backslashes it is not compiling